# How to check if a string is unique in a file and if it is write to another file in C#?

Tags: c#, file

I have two files F1.txt and F2.txt. F1.txt contains some contents like

```
U1,U2
U1,U5
U3,U4
U2,U1
U3,U4
```

Essentially U1,U2 and U2,U1 mean the same . So now I want to write the distinct contents to a file F2.txt i.e. after writing F2.txt should contain

```
U1,U2
U1,U5
U3,U4
```

I tried the below but that did not work out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringInFileTechchef
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\F1.txt"))
            {
                while((line=sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
                {
                    if (!File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\F2.txt").Contains(line))
                    {
                        //char[] array = line.ToCharArray();
                        //Array.Reverse(array);
                        //string temp = new string(array);

                        string temp1 = line.Substring(0, 2);
                        string temp2 = line.Substring(3, 2);

                        if (!File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\F2.txt").Contains(temp2 + "," + temp1))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\F2.txt"))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(line);
                                Console.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing ? How to achieve the scenario.

Comment: Is your problem with writing to text file or identifying distinct values?

Comment: What exactly didn't work out can you be more explicit about your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

Take each line and split it to a `string[]`

Sort the `string[]`

Join the `string[]` back to a `string`

Take the distinct `strings`

```
var distinct = File.ReadLines("TextFile2.txt")
    .Select(l => String.Join(",", l.Split(',').OrderBy(i => i)))
    .Distinct();

File.WriteAllLines("F2.txt", distinct);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueLines = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("F1.txt"))
{
    if (uniqueLines.Contains(line))
        continue;
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
    string reversedLine = string.Join(",", tokens.Reverse());
    if (uniqueLines.Contains(reversedLine))
        continue;
    uniqueLines.Add(line);
}
File.WriteAllLines("F2.txt", uniqueLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Basically assuming that there are two strings separated by comma always, I just filter them out using a HashSet. May be an overkill but works for small files.

```
#region

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

#endregion

namespace StringInFileTechchef
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<WordCombo> existingWordCombos = GetWordCombos(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\F2.txt"));
            HashSet<WordCombo> newWordCombos = GetWordCombos(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ganesh\Chiranjib\F1.txt"));

            foreach (WordCombo newWordCombo in newWordCombos)
            {
                existingWordCombos.Add(newWordCombo);
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (WordCombo existingWordCombo in existingWordCombos)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0},{1}{2}", existingWordCombo.SmallerWord, existingWordCombo.BiggerWord, Environment.NewLine);
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\F2.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
        }

        private static HashSet<WordCombo> GetWordCombos(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            HashSet<WordCombo> wordCombos = new HashSet<WordCombo>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] splitWords = line.Split(new[] {','});
                wordCombos.Add(new WordCombo(splitWords[0], splitWords[1]));
            }

            return wordCombos;
        }

        private class WordCombo
        {
            public string BiggerWord { get; private set; }
            public string SmallerWord { get; private set; }

            public WordCombo(string part1, string part2)
            {
                if (0 < string.Compare(part1, part2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    BiggerWord = part1;
                    SmallerWord = part2;
                }
                else
                {
                    BiggerWord = part2;
                    SmallerWord = part1;
                }
            }

            protected bool Equals(WordCombo other)
            {
                return string.Equals(BiggerWord, other.BiggerWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                       && string.Equals(SmallerWord, other.SmallerWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
                if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
                return Equals((WordCombo) obj);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    return ((BiggerWord != null ? BiggerWord.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^
                           (SmallerWord != null ? SmallerWord.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode() : 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```